# Is it possible to use jpa1 @notnull annotation?

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to use annotations like @notnull for jpa 1 ?
If not how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA 1.0 (or 2.0) do not have a @notnull annotation.

JPA 1.0 has, nullable on the @Column annotation.